# .tgz extract error like data --format violated

Tags: tar, extract

I have BSP folder for embedded computer.for booting from on board manufacturer given one .tgz  file.I am trying extract those file using the cmd like

```
tar -zvxf filename.tgz
```

I have logged as root and extracting that.

I am facing the few problem when I am extracting that.

```
invalid compressed data --format violated 
tar:unexpected EOF archive
tar:unexpected EOF archive
tar:Error is not recoverable:existing now
```

Comment: Judging from the error message, your tar-file is probably damaged... Also, are you really using Ubuntu 10.04? This question is off-topic then and you should upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu

Comment: @Wayne_Yux: The question is **not off topic** unless “[it] is *specific* to an end of life Ubuntu release” (highlight by me). I find this issue to be arguably independent of the Ubuntu release, because it's obviously about a broken archive file. Afaik the `tar` and `gzip` tools still work just fine on Ubuntu 10.04. :-)

Comment: I agree with @DavidFoerster  Edited the 10.04 from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.tgz`/`.tar.gz` archive is corrupt. You should probably download it again.

If you need to investigate further, `file filename.tgz` will take an educated guess what the file format is. For an actual gzip file the output would look more or less like this:

```
filename.tgz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
```

For a tar archive it would have the word “tar archive” in the format description like so:

```
filename.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Depending on the output of `file` you can take further steps:

- If the file is actually an uncompressed (instead of compressed) but mislabelled tar archive you can rename it to have the extension `.tar` and extract it with `tar -xf <FILE>` (just drop the `-z` flag because we don't want to decompress).
- If the file is a gzip stream, you can

  1. verify its integrity by extracting it do `/dev/null`:

     ```
     zcat filename.tgz >/dev/null
     ```
  2. peek inside to investigate further:

     ```
     zcat filename.tgz | file -s -
     ```